# Install php mysqli extension without installing mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

In my linux server, I have installed php v5.2.14 from source, and not installing mysql and apache. As this sever only used to run phpunit, so it's not neccsary to install mysql and apache. The prblem is that some unittest requir mysqli extension. So, I try to install mysqli extension using the code in the php source. however, when exectuing './configure', it stopped for following:

```
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /home/pu/php
checking for PHP includes... -I/home/pu/php/include/php -I/home/pu/php/include/php/main -I/home/pu/php/include/php/TSRM -I/home/pu/php/include/php/Zend -I/home/pu/php/include/php/ext -I/home/pu/php/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /home/pu/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /home/pu/php/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for MySQLi support... yes, shared
checking whether to enable embedded MySQLi support... no
mysql_config not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the mysql distribution
```

so i thought it maybe missing mysql causes this problem. 
Is there any solution for this. I don't want to install mysql server, just installing mysql client or driver is enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why did you choose 5.2.14? The 5.3 branch is now considered old, and 5.4 is the latest supported release.

Answer (score 1):

It requires to get compile options:

```
mysql_config (1)  - get compile options for compiling clients
```

I think you need php5-mysqlnd. Try to install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

This package doesn't have PHP or MySQL as dependencies:

```
php5-mysqlnd
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Depends: php5-common (= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3)
  Depends: phpapi-20090626+lfs
libc6
  Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10)
  Depends: libgcc1
  Depends: tzdata
libc-bin
libgcc1
  Depends: gcc-4.6-base (= 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
gcc-4.6-base
multiarch-support
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6)
tzdata
  Depends: debconf (>= 0.5)
  Depends: debconf-2.0
debconf
  PreDepends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4)
perl-base
  PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.14.20)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
dpkg
  PreDepends: coreutils (>= 5.93-1)
  PreDepends: libbz2-1.0
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.11)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
  PreDepends: tar (>= 1.23)
  PreDepends: xz-utils
  PreDepends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4)
coreutils
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
  Depends: install-info
  PreDepends: libacl1 (>= 2.2.51-5)
  PreDepends: libattr1 (>= 1:2.4.46-5)
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.15)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
install-info
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
libacl1
  Depends: libattr1 (>= 2.4.46-3)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libattr1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libselinux1
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.8)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
libbz2-1.0
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
tar
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.8)
xz-utils
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7)
  Depends: liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20110809)
liblzma5
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
zlib1g
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: multiarch-support
debconf-2.0
php5-common
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Depends: sed (>= 4.1.1-1)
sed
  Depends: dpkg (>= 1.15.4)
  Depends: install-info
  PreDepends: libc6 (>= 2.4)
  PreDepends: libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
phpapi-20090626+lfs
```

Finally, add `--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config` as Configure Option.